# Angular 1.5 $onInit not firing - typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, components

I'm attempting to convert parts of an Angular 1.5 application to TypeScript.  I'm not getting any errors but the $onInit() method is no longer firing.  I'm including my code that works (JavaScript) and the not working code (TypeScript)

Javascript version (working):

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .component('appProductList', {
        templateUrl: '/src/product-list/product-list.component.html',
        controller: ProductListController
    });

function ProductListController($location, ProductService) {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.$onInit = init;
    ctrl.selectProduct = selectProduct;

    function init(){
        ctrl.products = [];

        ProductService.getProducts()
            .then(res => {
                ctrl.products = res.data;
            }, error => console.log(error));
    }

    function selectProduct(product){
        $location.path('/product/' + product.id);
    }
}
```

TypeScript version ($onInit never fires):

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .component('appProductList', {
        templateUrl: '/src/product-list/product-list.component.html',
        controller: ProductListController
    });

class ProductListController{
    products: Array<Product>;

    constructor(private $location: ng.ILocationService, 
                private ProductService: ProductService) {}

    $onInit() {
        this.products = new Array<Product>();

        this.ProductService.getProducts()
            .then((res: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<Array<Product>>) => {
                this.products = res.data;
            }, error => console.log(error));
    } 

    selectProduct(product){
        this.$location.path('/product/' + product.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Im not sure about in typescript, but I know in general classes do not hoist so you need to declare them before you reference them. In other words try moving the class above your other code. And maybe just throw a console log in the constructor to make sure the class is working.

Comment: thank you @hsiung, moving the class above my angular declaration worked.. so functions hoist and classes do not?

Comment: correct, function statements (functions with names) will hoist, so therefore you can pretty much declare them anywhere in your scope and they'll be accessible. Check this out on classes from the mdn docs: 
"Hoisting

An important difference between function declarations and class declarations is that function declarations are hoisted and class declarations are not. You first need to declare your class and then access it, otherwise code like the following will throw a ReferenceError:"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer, classes do not hoist, therefor they must be declared before they are referenced.

From the MDN docs:

> **Hoisting:** 
>   An important difference between function declarations and class declarations is that function declarations are hoisted and class declarations are not. You first need to declare your class and then access it, otherwise code like the following will throw a ReferenceError:

[MDN: Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)